# Render JSX-element with .map() only if certain property of source object is not null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

```
    <h1>Trending today</h1>
    <ul>
      {this.state.trendingMovies.map((movie) => (
        <li key={movie.id}>
          <NavLink to={`/movies/${movie.id}`} className="movie-link">
            {movie.title}
          </NavLink>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
```

Here's what I got. Right now, I am rendering the whole array - but I need to render {movie.title} is not null. Please help me with writing a ternary.

Comment: You could either return `null` from the `map` function when you do not wish to render anything, or subset the array before the `map` function using the `filter` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just filter them out first:

```
this.state.trendingMovies.filter(movie => movie.title).map(...
```

or if you really want it only if it's not null (empty string is OK):

```
this.state.trendingMovies.filter(movie => movie.title !== null).map(...
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering `null`/`undefined`/`false` [are ignored](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored) by renderer, [you may use](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) `Array.prototype.map()` with [short-circuited](http://Short-Circuit_Evaluation)  `&&`(which will be even more compact than ternary) to return either `false` or `<li>` JSX, based on desired condition, so you ***won't need to do extra loop for `.filter()`***:

```
{this.state.trendingMovies.map((movie) => !!movie.title && (
        <li key={movie.id}>
          <NavLink to={`/movies/${movie.id}`} className="movie-link">
            {movie.title}
          </NavLink>
        </li>
      ))}
```